# Split angular code in multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to split my angular code and I have some problems.

At the beggining I had an "undefined function" about my controllers" and now I have "Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp.controllers.accueil" and "Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DmyApp.controllers.accueil%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.8%252F%2524injector%..." errors.
I found some others questions looking similar but I can't find my error(s)...

[image: Here there is my folders]

This is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="M2-SCMN">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="web/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="web/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/accueil.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/utilisateur.js"></script>
        <title>AngularProj</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" >
    <div ng-view></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

My app.js  (I would like to have 1file/module (user, homepage...)) :

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute', 
    'myApp.controllers.accueil',
    'myApp.controllers.utilisateur'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/accueil.html', controller: 'AccueilCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/connexion', {templateUrl: 'views/connexion.html', controller: 'ConnexionCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

And the accueil controllers looks like :

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers.accueil')
    .controller('AccueilCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.texte = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you haven't actually created your **myApp.controllers.accueil** module in the accueil controller file, you are just trying to retrieve the module.

You first need to create the **myApp.controllers.accueil** module. I think your confusion has come from the difference between how you create a module and how you retrieve one.

Taken from the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) (see under Creation versus Retrieval):

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

So you're actually trying to retrieve a module that doesn't exist.

Your controller code should be like this instead:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers.accueil', [])
.controller('AccueilCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.texte = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';
});
```